# How to detect if the user is holding the iPhone with his hand

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multi-touch

I'm looking for a way to determine if the user is holding his iPhone with his hand in objective-c.
The problem is that for some reasons, the multitouch layer in my iPhone game doesn't work as expected when the user puts his iPhone on something (table, chair, sofa etc.) and uses it only with one hand. It doesn't depend on the orientation.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Some iPhones have a great build in feature for that: Just check the signal strength...

Comment: @kapep: I'd +100 if I could for that comment.

Comment: @Marco It sounds like you're trying to bail water out of the boat rather than fix the holes in it. It would be better for you to directly fix the issue where it doesn't work on something, than create something new to indirectly resolve the problem.

Comment: @Jonathan I've been testing it a lot and this is what happens: 1. I put the iPhone on the table touching it with the right hand, at a certain point the multitouch layer gets inaccurate 2. I touch slightly the edge of the iPhone with the other hand without even moving the iPhone and the layer starts working perfectly. I'm starting to think that it doesn't depend on my code. Also my game uses multitouch in quite a particular way but still, no problems at all when I hold the iPhone in my hand and I've been testing it for months.

Comment: @Marco, I would try it on someone else's device (preferably one of the same model, and another of a different model), to determine whether it's your phone or not, touching you phone shouldn't have any affect on the accuracy of the touchscreen.

Comment: @Jonahan, I tried that as well, I've tested it on 2 iPhone 2G, 2 different iPhone 4, an iPhone 3G, an iPhone 3GS and an iPod 4th generation, getting the same results.

Comment: And what happens if someone else do the same thing with your iPhone ? The problem could be you (electrostatical problem with your body).

Comment: @Jonathan, It's not just me, the same problem happens with several people using it as well. Also, if the cable is plugged in everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CMMotionManager.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Just keep a track of the device "userAcceleration" changes and analyse it. If it does not change, you can guess it's on a non moving object. If it change, you can guess it's into the hands of the user. The problem is that may not be perfect and need some precise adjustments and debug to find the correct values you may test (idea : you should make some test to see what happens if the iPhone is on a non moving object into a moving one like a car, a bus, a train, ...).

But that should work.

Comment: +1 because I think it's the right answer to my original question. Unfortunately, I've realised that it's not good enough for me because people wearing gloves or using thick covers may still have problems. I'm going to accept it as answer at some point but I'd like to leave it open for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to overlay a kludge, you need to work out what is wrong with the implementation of the multitouch layer that means that it is not correctly activated unless the device is being held in someone's hand. The device being held in the hand is almost certainly only a proxy for what the real difference is in conditions between when the layer is working and when it is not... you need to figure out what the real difference in conditions is.

For instance: perhaps you're only correctly registering the multi-touch movements if there is a stationary touch somewhere else in the layer—inadvertent touch from holding the device?

Comment: thanks Duncan, I've been trying to think about that you said but it really seems to be related to the device. As I wrote, if I put the iPhone on the table tapping with my right hand and I slightly touch the edge (not the screen) with the left hand everything works fine. In other words I don't need to hold it to make it work. Also, the problem doesn't occur when I'm in debug mode and I'm using only the right hand because the cable is plugged in and it makes things work. As you can understand it's really tricky to debug!

Comment: Hmm. Some sort of massive static electricity issue? That might affect the touchscreen performance. You said you've tried multiple devices... have you tried multiple _tables_? Such as one in a completely different environment? A light touch on the side of the phone and plugging in the cable both have the possibility of earthing the device... that could be what is going on. :)

Comment: yes I've tried on different surfaces. It happens on tables, sofas, chairs, always with the same results. I should probably try holding it with thick gloves, maybe it's a matter of heat?

Comment: Just tried with gloves, the problem is still noticeable but less severe. I agree with you, my hand might be earthing the device, do you think I can do something about it?

Comment: So with gloves, the problem is somewhere between hand-holding and not touching the device? That does lean in the direction of supporting the idea of it being something to do with electrostatic charge. I now see Oliver above had suggested the same thing too—I hadn't seen that. I really can't see how heat would make any difference, other than in a single, faulty unit—if there were that kind of issue there would have been widespread reports of this. Need to get to the bottom of why minor differences would throw off your multi-touch gestures so much more than others. Over-specific algorithms?

Comment: thanks @Ducan-Babbage, I actually tried using an Apple sample project called "Touches" and I could still reproduce the problem on different devices. I guess I can't do so much about it.